# How to output asian characters in Logbacks' HTML format

Tags: java, logback

I am using Logback to enable logging statements within my code. Currently when I am logging information displayed in asian characters ( Chinese, Korean, Japanese etc ) they appear similar to `æ?±äº¬éƒ½`.

How can I output the proper characters into my logs? For instance, Tokyo should output `東京都` not
`æ?±äº¬éƒ½`

I have enabled the UTF-8 character set within my logback.xml config file:

```
<encoder class="ch.qos.logback.core.encoder.LayoutWrappingEncoder">
        <charset>UTF-8</charset>
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.html.HTMLLayout">
                <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS}%thread%level%logger%line%msg</pattern>
        </layout>           
</encoder>
```

Comment: Are the characters being written to the log wrongly, or are you viewing the log wrongly? What do you see if you inspect a log file with a hex editor?

Comment: Good question - I will get back to you with the hex results.

Comment: The output in a hex editor: `<td class="Message">Tokyo : ???</td>`

Comment: Er, i was more thinking of what the hex looked like, rather than the characters. To troubleshoot encoding problems, it helps to look at the bytes rather than the characters.

Comment: My apologies - bytes are: 3F 3F 3F representing the ???

Comment: I changed eclipse's default encoding to UTF-8 and ran it again, now  the hex is: `E6 9D B1 E4 BA AC E9 83 BD`

Comment: Just to clarify, when you talk about the log, you mean the text written to the Eclipse console, right? This is not being written to a file, right?

Comment: Both actually - writing to file now works ( see my answer below ) however console does not work at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the logback html file to display correctly, a custom CSS must be specified with `font-family: 'lucida sans unicode', tahoma, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;` (or a similar font) specified where its needed. For instance I have it set for `TR.even` and `TR.odd` classes.

As an aside, it turns out that eclipse has issues with these character sets. I was unable to get asian characters to print period, even with simple examples such as

`Locale locale = new Locale("zh", "CN");
 System.out.println(locale.getDisplayLanguage(Locale.SIMPLIFIED_CHINESE));`

I ran the same code in NetBeans and it outputs flawlessly.

In the case of eclipse I changed the encoding to UTF-8 wherever possible via system preferences, as well as set the default font to the above font with no resolution. I even went so far as to download a new copy of eclipse, extract it to a new directory and create a new workspace before setting everything to UTF-8/changing the font and then creating a test case, again with no resolution. For NetBeans no change was required.

--EDIT--

Also please note this seems to be a windows issue only - My home development machine is Linux and it ran the above code perfectly with no alterations to preferences and using a new install of Eclipse.

Comment: This matches what happens when i tried this. Basically, regardless of what the program may be doing, Eclipse's internal console is in the platform default character set. In my case, that was MacRoman (which i didn't realise had survived into the this century!), and i saw gibberish like you. Although, then i saved the file as UTF-8, and suddenly it all worked. Who knows, man, who knows.

Comment: Awsome - just makes it mind-bendingly painful trying to validate input/output when the output method is insane.